# Appropriate MMORPG battle system for Android-oriented MMORPG?

Tags: mmo, rpg, combat

I need a tip for a game I'm making. Because of many issues I want to make a 2D mmorpg:

- A 2D game is easier to code (I'm using ActionScript3 / Starling).
- I can more likely find preexistent graphics, and handling them is easier.
- Fundamentally: I don't want to eat the device's memory!! Common devices here have at most 1GB RAM memory.

But when I think about battle systems, I imagine stuff like [Argentum Online](http://www.comunidadargentum.com/) and [Tibia](https://secure.tibia.com/mmorpg/free-multiplayer-online-role-playing-game.php). Those battle systems were OK on mouse-keyboard based systems. AO's battle system will be **really** hard to use (specially by any spellcaster class) in devices like Samsung S3 mini.

OTOH when I think in systems like Pokemon or [Golden Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Sun), both of them being turn-based,  I ask myself about the interation: battles would be locked (they have a protocol, you cannot suddenly leave a fight, you can take as long as you want in each turn,...) which is not acceptable in a mmorpg for many reason (mmorpg users do not expect a protocol, they expect to leave a fight as they'd like, they would HATE users who suddenly go AFK on the middle of a battle without having opportunity to act).

What battle interaction would be a good balance between mobile-device-friendliness and not being a pain in the ass for game dynamics? Suggestions are accepted here (we cannot expect game design have absolute decisions at all).